# How to checkbox to enable a button in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
self.label_5 = tk.Checkbutton(self.master, text="I agree to the", bg='white', width=14,font=("Arial", 8), command= activator)
self.label_5.place(x=112, y=410)
self.button_2 = tk.Button(text='Proceed', width=20, bg='white', state = tk.DISABLED, bd=1, 
highlightbackground='black', font=("Arial", 10)).place(x=208, y = 512)

def activator(button):
    if (self.button_2 ['state'] == tk.DISABLED):
        self.button_2 ['state'] = tk.NORMAL
    else:
        self.button_2['state'] = tk.DISABLED
```

I want to enable the proceed button after I checked the checkbutton but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: You assigned `None` to `self.button_2` (the return value of `.place()`), rather than the actual button.

Comment: so the self.button 2 must be at the function?

Comment: Read [AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1101765/7414759)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the following changes to your code:

- You have to refer to the function named `activator` as `self.activator` when giving it to the `Button`(`button_2`) as `command`.
- You have to change the `parameter` named `button` of the function named `activator` to `self`.
- And the most important thing you need to do is move the part of code where you are placing the `Button`(`button_2`) and the `Checkbutton`(`label_5`), to a new line. Like I have done in the code below. The reason for doing so is that `pack`, `grid` and `place` always `return` `None`. And when you do it in the same line where you have created your widgets and assigned them to a variable i.e. `button_2` and `label_5`, the value `None` gets stored in that widget.

Here's the corrected code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = tk.Tk()
        self.master.geometry('550x550')

        self.label_5 = tk.Checkbutton(self.master, text="I agree to the", bg='white', width=14, font=("Arial", 8),
                                      command=self.activator)
        self.label_5.place(x=112, y=410)

        self.button_2 = tk.Button(text='Proceed', width=20, bg='white', state=tk.DISABLED, bd=1,
                                  highlightbackground='black', font=("Arial", 10))
        self.button_2.place(x=208, y=512)

        self.master.mainloop()

    def activator(self):

        if self.button_2['state'] == tk.DISABLED:
            self.button_2['state'] = tk.NORMAL

        else:
            self.button_2['state'] = tk.DISABLED


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test()
```